# Cycle2 Carousel Pager Not Functioning

Tags: jquery, carousel, jquery-cycle, pager

I'm having a problem getting the carousel pager in a Cycle2 configuration to work.

http://tylonius.net/gallerytest/lifestyle-gallery.php

The pager code appears to be rendered correctly by the script, and the main slides work properly, but neither the thumbnails, nor the navigation arrows function the way they should.

I'm also not getting any errors in the console.

Is there a jQuery conflict somewhere I'm not catching?

Thanks in advance for any help!

ty

Comment: you have a z-index problem where arrows container is blocking the pager

Comment: It's always something simple! Thanks, Charlie!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a z-index issue, wherein another element was covering the pager.

Hat tip to [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) for the answer.